# Draw a line for every key and its values in a map - resulting in a star - how?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics

I would like to represent a map (e.g its keys and values) as a star, each key represents a line and every dot on that line is a value which belongs to that key, given a map like this:

```
{
    "Key 1" : [Value1, Value2,Value3,...],
    "Key 2" : [Value1, Value2,Value3,...],
    "Key 3" : [Value1, Value2,Value3,...],
    "Key 4" : [Value1, Value2,Value3,...],
    ...
}
```

[image]

My idea in JavaScript looks like this:

```
var angleCuts = (360.0 / (Object.keys(posts).length) + 1); //angles for each line
$.each(Object.keys(posts), function (i, key) { //iterate through every key
    var slope = Math.tan((angleCuts * (i + 1)) * (Math.PI / 180.0));
    var postCounter = slope < 0 ? -1 : 1; //align start x value according to positive or negative slope
    var func = function (x) {
        postCounter += 1 / slope; //postCounter increments for every value in a map
        return (slope * x + t);
    }
    $.each(posts[key], function (id, post) { //iterate through every value
        var x = postCounter;
        var y = func(postCounter);
        //draw point(x,y)
    });
});
```

But this only covers the upper hemisphere and I don't know how I could make this to make a star (or circle, depends on the amount of keys).

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Vertical lines are not possible - of course.

Comment: Once you have your angle, `sin(angle)` gives the X coordinate, and `cos(angle)` gives the Y coordinate.

Comment: Also if those lines are perfect diagonals and the lines aren't even length (not encompassed in a circle, but a square), I think you could generate the star in one loop. Assuming counter variable `j`, vertical line uses `(w/2,j)`, horizontal line uses `(j,h/2)`, forward slash uses `(j,j)`, back slash uses `(w-j-1,j)`.

Comment: But the angle doesn't change for the values of the same key, how do I get a line out of `sin(angle)` and `cos(angle)`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  'JOHN': [2, 8, 12, 20],
  'RINGO': [4, 10, 12, 20],
  'PAUL': [8, 10, 12, 14],
  'GEORGE': [5, 10, 12, 18],
  'LUKE': [2, 10, 16, 20],
  'LEIA': [3, 10, 18, 22]
}

const objects = Object.keys(data);
const scale = 7;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.font = '14px Arial';

// Calculate the points of the star
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var angle = -2 * Math.PI / objects.length;

ctx.beginPath();
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  var x, y;
  data[objects[i]].forEach(v => {
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    x = centerX + Math.cos(i * angle) * v * scale;
    y = centerY + Math.sin(i * angle) * v * scale;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.fillRect(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4);
  });
  ctx.fillText(objects[i], x, y);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```